# JSON Output Sequence

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, jersey

I wish to use POST to get JSON Output from web services. When I try the program on localhost, it works well as the output fulfill my requirement, but when I upload to Google App Engine, I try to get the output and the sequence is reverse.

```
{
  "Data": {
    "token": "****"
  },
  "AppData": {
    "status": "success",
    "message": [
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Output from GAE

```
{
    "AppData": {
        "status": "success",
        "message": [
        ""
        ]
    },
    "Data": {
        "token": "****"
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
public Response getSAppData(int id, String email, String password){
    Map<String, AppData> AppDataHM = new HashMap<>(); 
    Map<String, Data> DataHM1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> DataHM2 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Object, Object> ADHMDHM = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
    Data data = DataHM.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
    List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();

    if(data != null){
        message.add("");
        AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("success", message));
        DataHM1.put("Data", data);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(AppDataHM);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(DataHM1);
        String ADHMDHM1 = new Gson().toJson(ADHMDHM);
        return Response.status(200).entity(ADHMDHM1).build();
    }
    else{
        message.add("Your login information is invalid. Please try with the correct information");
        AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("error", message));
        DataHM2.put("Data", data2);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(AppDataHM);
        ADHMDHM.putAll(DataHM2);
        String ADHMDHM2 = new Gson().toJson(ADHMDHM);
        return Response.status(200).entity(ADHMDHM2).build();
    }   
}
```

Code for generating the output.

Thank in advance for every user that helps to point out the mistake.

Comment: I don't think sequence will affect processing of JSON.

Comment: Hi. @SachinGupta Is there any way to maintain the sequence of JSON? As the sequence really important to me.

Comment: Check answer section for that

Comment: Thanks @SachinGupta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to maintain sequence of output, you should use `LinkedHashMap`. as `HashMap` doesn't maintain ordering on keys or values. But `LinkedHashMap`  preserves the insertion order.

Try to change your code to `LinkedHashMap`, then it should work.

Comment: Hi. @SachinGupta. Thanks for your answer. It works. As I can't accept an answer in 5 minutes, I will accept it later.